# Conduit Toolbar and Windows Application

Tags: windows, toolbar, launcher

I have a button inside of "Conduit Toolbar". "OnClick" I need to launch MyApp.exe (if the application already installed) or to open download page...

I know that if it was my own toolbar then app launching and other things are easy!
But I must use this @#%#ing "conduit".

I'm looking for any help (code/links/pictures...)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up!
We just made a little http server that starts on windows startup.
And now I can send from toolbar any message to localhost and let the server do the rest.

I hope this answer will be helpful for somebody.